# Adding new OpenGL shapes from the list in QT

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I want to create program which will add dynamically new shapes using OpenGL from the list.
For example: there are 3 triangles, 2 circles and 2 rectangles on my list, and these shapes should be displayed at `QWidget` window. There should be possibility to add/delete new shapes during the program.

I haven't got where to start. My teacher told me to use list of objects, and each type of shape should have their own class.

My project looks like:

```
|- headers
  -- grafika.h
  -- mainwindow.h
|- sources
  -- main.cpp
  -- grafika.cpp
  -- mainwindow.cpp
```

This is my example code of `paintGL()` method

```
void Grafika::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0,0,-5);
    glRotatef(-xRot,1,0,0);
    glRotatef(-yRot,0,1,0);
    glRotatef(-zRot,0,0,1);
    glRotatef(alpha,0,0,1);
    glColor4fv(fColor);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(-0.2,-0.2,0);
    glVertex3f(0.2,-0.2,0);
    glVertex3f(0,0.2,0);
    glEnd();
    shapesList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(shapesList,GL_COMPILE);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(-0.2,0.2,0);
        glVertex3f(0.2,0.2,0);
        glVertex3f(0.2,-0.2,0);
        glVertex3f(-0.2,-0.2,0);
        glEnd();
    glEndList();
    glCallList(shapesList);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question is where should I start? My problem is i haven't got idea how to do it. How to make mechanism of adding new shapes into my opengl widget?